# Retry cancelled APIs on location change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, firebase-analytics

Whenever the window location changes API calls called are canceled by the browser.
I am firing analytics events on-click of a button which also takes to a subdomain and refreshes the page, so there is a race condition now. Sometimes the event is resolved and sometimes it is canceled by the browser.
Tried to resolve it using service worker. Not getting callbacks in sync for canceled events
the possible workaround I found are as follows

1. wait for the event to be resolved before redirecting
2. store in local storage and fire on returning back
3. pass the event to be fired as query param to the subdomain and fire it there

Is there a better solution for this ?

[image]

Comment: ping or sendBeacon is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Define a new Analytics component at global level that is not impacted with route changes.

1. Add a generic logic in Analytics component to receive data and hit
   API.
2. Now location change of any component / destroy event will not impact cancelling of API call.
3. just the event need to be hit rest Analytics component will take care.

> ```
> <Provider> -- redux store -->
>     **<Analytics >** - analytics logic , use redux to notify about event or other logic
>     
> <App></App> - has route and all other logic
>
> </provider>
> ```

Comment: my use-case also includes navigating to payment which is external.

Comment: ping or sendBeacon is what i was looking for